# How to get second directory name in the perforce file path?

Tags: awk, sed, directory

I need to get the directory in the second column after depot. For example given the below file(s) list, I need "Directory2" as the output.

```
//depot/Directory2/Dir3/Dir4/Dir5/Dir6/Filename1

//depot/Directory2/Dir3/Dir4/Dir5/Dir6/Filename2
```

Comment: `cut -d / -f 4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F / '{ print $4; }'
```

will give you the second entry in the path. It's the fourth when parsed: the first is the empty string before the first `/`, the second is the empty string between the two `/`, and third is `depot`.

Comment: I want the same but in reverse order. So in this example the 3rd directory from the right (so not Dir6, Dir5) but Dir4. How to do this..??

Comment: @danger89 you should ask a new question rather than piggy-back on a slightly related one.

Comment: Well could be, or people will also end-up here since this answer is already well indexed by search engines, and people find directly the answer for reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` assuming you have the lines in file `input.txt`:

```
sed 's|.*depot/\([^/]*\)/.*|\1|' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using grep:

```
grep -Po 'depot/\K[^/]*'
```